# add ajax success function callback to jquery function

Tags: jquery

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.sendAuditToHandler = function (options) {

            var defaultSettings = {
                'url': '../SentinelOperationsUI/GenericHandler.ashx'
            };

            var objectToSend = {};

            var opts = $.extend(defaultSettings, options);

            $(this).find('input[type=text], select').each(function (i, val) {

                var objectKey = $(val).attr('class');
                var objectValue = $(val).val();

                objectToSend[objectKey] = objectValue;
            });

            objectToSend = JSON.stringify(objectToSend);

            $.ajax({
                url: opts.url,
                data: { 'AuditObject': objectToSend },
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });

            return this;

        };
    })(jQuery);
```

What i would like to use is something like to make use of the ajax success function in my function call. Something like

```
sendAuditToHandler({ /* some options */ }, success: function() { //ajax success callback function }...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either pass it in as a normal parameter, or as part of the existing options hash.

```
$.fn.sendAuditToHandler = function (options, onSuccess) {
    // etc.
        $.ajax({
            url: opts.url,
            data: { 'AuditObject': objectToSend },
            success: onSuccess
        });
```

Then when you call it:

```
sendAuditToHandler({ /* some options */ }, function(data) {
    // Whatever you want.
    alert("ohai");
});
```

Or as part of the options:

```
$.ajax({
    url: opts.url,
    data: { 'AuditObject': objectToSend },
    success: opts.onSuccess
});
```

And when you call it:

```
sendAuditToHandler({
    url: "the url",
    // other options, then the method.
    onSuccess: function(data) {
        // Whatever you want.
        alert("ohai");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but why cant i only pass the onsuccess in the arguments? do i need to pass options, eventhough they have default settings?

Comment: @Johan I don't know what you're asking. You can pass whatever you want in the options, including the success function.

Comment: im asking if its ok to only pass the success function, and skip the options :)

Comment: never mind, i just forgot to add a `{`, thanks for your detailed answer :)

Comment: @Johan Ah, I understand :) Yep, as you discovered, you can :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call your success function inside the ajax call

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: opts.url, 
   data: { 'AuditObject': objectToSend }, 
   success: function (data) { 
        options.success();
   } 
});
```